# JSON parsing takes way too long

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft JSON to parse some output from an API. However, the API result is nearly 2.5 MB, and parsing out the entire file just to find the data I need takes a long time. Here is a snippet of the API output:

```
{
"response": {
    "success": 1,
    "current_time": 1416085203,
    "raw_usd_value": 0.2,
    "usd_currency": "metal",
    "usd_currency_index": 5002,
    "items": {
        "A Brush with Death": {
            "defindex": [
                30186
            ],
            "prices": {
                "6": {
                    "Tradable": {
                        "Craftable": [
                            {
                                "currency": "metal",
                                "value": 3,
                                "last_update": 1414184620,
                                "difference": -0.165
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

My code is supposed to find the only object that is a child of the items object with the number '5021' in the defindex array, and pull out the currency and value data. Here is the code I use to find the data:

```
dynamic result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(priceFile);
int keyprice = 0;
foreach(var items in result.response.items){
            foreach(var item in items){
                string indexstr = item.defindex.ToString();
                if (indexstr.Contains(defindex))
                {
                    foreach(var price in item.prices){
                        foreach (var quality in price)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", quality.Tradable.Craftable[0].value, quality.Tradable.Craftable[0].currency);
                            keyprice = quality.Tradable.Craftable[0].value;
                            return keyprice;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Ideally, the code should only take up to 10 seconds to run.

Comment: And how long does it take now? (And what's the point in all the break statements? If you only want the first element, just take the first element...)

Comment: `indexstr = item.defindex.ToString(); if (indexstr.Contains("5021"))..` is so ... interesting way of comparing integers. At very least it will not distinguish 55021 vs 5021.

Comment: Right now, it takes several minutes (over 10) to complete. Also, the purpose of the strange comparison is because item.defindex is not an int. I am sure that it is the only defindex containing that string of numbers, though.

Comment: You can work with your class mate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950609/c-iterating-through-nested-json#26950609

Comment: Looks more like TF2 item sniffing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an class for response object, and then use code similar to the following. I tested on a 2.8MB json file and it averaged about 1.2 second, also try using fastJSON (there is a nuget package) - it is the fastest parser I have found.

```
        string fileName = @"c:\temp\json\yourfile.json";
        string json;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            json = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        response myResponse = fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<response>(json);

        var item = myResponse.First(i => i.defindex == "5051");

        foreach (var price in item.prices)
        {
            foreach (var quality in price)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", quality.Tradable.Craftable[0].value, quality.Tradable.Craftable[0].currency);
                keyprice = quality.Tradable.Craftable[0].value;
                return keyprice;
            }
        }
```